# Google Cloud Platform partner interconnect API - Only approved partners can create interconnects with type PARTNER

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-interconnect

I am new in GCP. I'm trying to create Partner Interconnect by using GCP rest api, and receiving the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.interconnectType': 'PARTNER'. Only approved partners can create interconnects with type PARTNER."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.interconnectType': 'PARTNER'. Only approved partners can create interconnects with type PARTNER."
 }
}
```

My Request body is:

```
{
  "description": "tesinterconnect",
  "name": "testintrconnect",
  "linkType": "LINK_TYPE_ETHERNET_10G_LR",
  "interconnectType": "PARTNER",
  "adminEnabled": true,
  "customerName": "equinix"
}
```

My project is connected with official partners of GCP(Equinix) and I'm able to create Partner interconnect using GCP console.

Anything is missing in my request body or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are a customer of GCP, and using Equinix as a partner, you should be creating VLAN attachments following the [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/partner/creating-vlan-attachments). After you've completed those steps, you'll have a pairing key which you can use on the Equinix portal to provision your VLAN on your Equinix Cloud Exchange connection.

The API you are attempting to call into is for creating Partner Interconnects; that's something only [approved service provider partners](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/concepts/service-providers) of Google can do.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Rob's comment, I believe you should try to connect to GCP using Equinix APIs instead. I am guessing this should [help](https://developer.equinix.com/content/equinix-cloud-exchange-fabric-2#content-connect-google) as they have listed out all the steps for PARTNER (Equinix) to connect to GCP. The link also has sample REST API calls which should help you to resolve your request payload.